# Adding a Slogan to Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wanting to have it so that above the Nav is a large logo and slogan, and as the screen size shrinks below 768px the position of both elements changes.

So to start with it would be like so 
[image]

and change to this

[image]

How would I go about this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Edited to be less bloated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the logo `<img>` twice... once in the top and once in the menu.

Then hide/show the appropriate --- use grid responsive utils: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

i.e.
`.visible-xs` on the inner menu logo
&
`.hidden-xs` on the top logo

*(I'm assuming BS3 here.)*

**EDIT:** See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/fyvjq9b7/)

Comment: I noticed that part was a separate question and removed it.

The major problem is figuring out how to do the logo +  slogan on column above nav-fixed-top.

Comment: Same principle applies - slogan gets a .hidden-xs, logo gets a col-xs-12 with an inner `<img style="witdth: 100%">`

Comment: Could you quickly code fiddle it for me? I'm not getting you

Comment: Sure - added JSFiddle link.

Comment: ha, like the class name. I agree that the idea of logo and slogan don't look very good at all, but they're pretty adamant that's the design they want even after saying not particularly keen.